# Matching a pattern on different lines in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a pattern on different lines using this

```
my $line = <>;

if($line =~ /hello\nthere/m){
    say "matched";
}
else{
    say "no match";
}
```

However, when I run the program with a file containing this text, it doesn't match.

```
hello
there
```

I've tried using the dot operator (.) and the /s modifier as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Perl, but doesn't the diamond operator iterate line by line? You won't get both `hello` and `there` together at the same time this way.

Comment: You can set some variables so that it'll eat all the input at once, but yeah. By default you only get a line at a time.

Comment: I completely forgot about that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<>` reads only one line of input, unless you clear the `$/` variable.

```
my $all_lines = do { local $/; <> };
```

Then, you can match

```
$all_lines =~ /hello\nthere/;
```

No need for `/m`, as it changes the meaning of `^` and `$`, neither of which is present in the regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I completely forgot about it reading line by line.

Comment: Is the change in $/ only local to the subroutine call, or is it a global change? Example, if I change it on subroutine, would it be reset to default in another subroutine?

Comment: `local` changes its value in the nearest scope, and `do {...}` limits the scope.