# Matching multiple line indents in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to count the number of spaces of indent per each line using this code:

```
my $line = do {
    local $/;
    <>
};

if ( $line =~ /\n(\s+)/g ) {
    my $count = length($1);
    say "amount of spaces are $count";
}
```

The input file has this text:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
  import sys
    x = 1
      testing
```

But my program displays the number of spaces for only the very first line

```
amount of spaces are 2
```

I want it to also return

```
amount of spaces are 4
amount of spaces are 6
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: `if ( /.../g )` is a code smell in Perl.

Comment: Can you please clarify what that means? I'm assuming it's related to bad coding.

Comment: @mob: *"code smell"* is a language smell in English, as is *"language smell"*. Even legitimate jargon makes communícation difficult enough as it is; we don't need to supplement that with playground words.

Comment: `/g` is for global matching -- checking if the regular expression is matched more than once. But there's no need to check that in an `if` statement. If `if (/.../g) { ... }` executes the conditional block, then so will `if (/.../) { ... }`

Comment: ah right. Yes, that's correct. I picked up on that once you pointed it out. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJane: **mob** means that using the `/g` modifier in scalar context is a ***red flag*** for a likely coding error. It adds a state to the object string so that matches will be made only one at a time.

Comment: How can a line contain a newline? Stop trying to match `\n` when you're iterating on `<>`.

Comment: @CAustin How does that imply that a line contains a newline? It's saying to match if the next line has an indentation. The `$/` variable has been set to undef so it doesn't read line by line anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an `if` instead of a `while`

An easy fix is to switch to line-by-line processing:

```
while (<>) {
    my ($leading_spaces) = /^(\s*)/;
    my $count = length $leading_spaces;
    say "amount of spaces are $count";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works, however, the program now takes input line by line. I won't be able to do new line matches anymore. Is there a way of taking the input as one whole file and still be able to get the correct output?

Comment: @BobJane: I don't understand what you mean by *".I won't be able to do new line matches anymore"*. Only the special characters `^` and `$` can be affected by reading the input in lines, but your code uses neither of these. A linefeed character `"\n"` behaves exactly like any other character.

Comment: @Borodin I mean that I won't be able to match `$line =~ /hello\nthere/m` stuff like this. Example, I want to read and check if a line has indentation and I want to be able to use that line to check what the next line contains. This is what I am referring to.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414935/matching-a-pattern-on-different-lines-in-perl/46415016#46415016

Answer (score 0):

You can still slurp your whole file into $line and then do (destructively):

```
while ( $line =~ s/\n([\t ]+)// )
{
    my $count = length($1);
    say "amount of spaces are $count";
}
```

Note I don't think you want to use \s as that includes \n which will give you a single match on several consecutive blank lines. I'm using both a tab \t and a literal space to match instead. If you already are expanding tabs you could remove that of course.